# @Context request in abstract class

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have following class structure (I try to post only the code relevant to my question):

these three single classes:

```
abstract public class AbstractController {
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;
    [...]
    protected int getSomething() {
        if (request == null) {
            return doSomething();
        } else {
            return doSomethingElse();
        }
    }
    [...]
}


@Produces("application/json")
abstract public class AbstractPageController extends AbstractController {
    [...]
}


public class BaseController extends AbstractPageController {
    private int selectedSomething;
    [...]
    public BaseController(@QueryParam("monthIdentifier") Integer something) throws SQLException {
        selectedSomething = getSomething();
        [...]
    }
    public int getSelectedSomething() { return selectedSomething; }
}
```

and multiple classes with following structure:

```
@Path("/foo/bar")
@Produces("application/json")
public class FooBarController extends BaseController {

    @GET
    public Response renderPage() {
        int something = getSelectedSomething();
    }
}
```

The problem isbasically, that the `request` variable in `AbstractController` is always null.

I need something based on the request, and I need it for each request.

When I rewrite the code so that I access the request in each `FooBarController` and pass it to the `getSelectedFunction()` it works.
But that is ugly and hard to maintain, I don't want to change each FooBarController because there are a lot. Am I accessing `request` in `AbstractController` the wrong way or is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to access the injected parameter in the constructor of a subclass.  The class needs to be fully created before its fields are injected.

```
public BaseController(@QueryParam("monthIdentifier") Integer something) throws SQLException {
        selectedSomething = getSomething(); // <-- injection in superclass has not happened yet
```

So the answer is:  It's possible, but not from the constructor.  If you accessed it from a REST endpoint it would not be NULL.